# $\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{l=0}^k \binom{n}{k} \binom{k}{l} (-1)^{k-l} s_l ?= \sum_{l=0}^n \sum_{k=l}^n (-1)^{n-k} \binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{l}s_l $

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I want to prove 
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{l=0}^k \binom{n}{k} \binom{k}{l} (-1)^{k-l} s_l 
?= \sum_{l=0}^n \sum_{k=l}^n (-1)^{k-l} \binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{l}s_l = s_n
\end{align}
I can understand the last step using

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=l}^{n} (-1)^{k-l} \binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{l} = \delta_{nl}
\end{align}

But what about the first step?

---

Note added :

This problem was due to proving following binomial transformation

\begin{align}
  s_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{(n-k)! k!} b^{n-k} c^k a_k
\end{align}
Its inverse formula is given as
\begin{align}
  a_n = c^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{(n-k)! k!} (-1)^{n-k} b^{n-k} s_k
\end{align}
What I want to prove is the above is really inverse.

So I start

\begin{align}
  s_n &= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{(n-k)! k!} b^{n-k} c^k a_k
 = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{(n-k)! k!} b^{n-k} c^k \left( c^{-k} \sum_{l=0}^{k} \frac{k!}{(k-l)! l!} (-1)^{k-l} b^{k-l} s_l\right)   \\
& = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{(n-k)! k!} b^{n-k}  \left(  \sum_{l=0}^{k} \frac{k!}{(k-l)! l!} (-1)^{k-l} b^{k-l} s_l\right)   
\end{align}

and to do right computation, I guess some identity and that's what i want to know.

Comment: Did you mean $(-1)^{k-l}$ instead of  $(-1)^{n-k}$ in the middle term?

Comment: @StefanLafon, Thanks, I edit it!

Comment: Permute the sums and note that the missing terms are all zero, $\binom{k}{l}=0$ for $l<k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic double sum transformation:

$\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{l=0}^k t(k, l)
=\sum_{l=0}^n \sum_{k=l}^n t(k, l)
$.

This is all $k$ and $l$ with
$0 \le l \le k \le n$.

We also need
$\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{k} \binom{n}{k}
=0$
if $n > 0$
and
$=1$ if $n = 0$.

This is the expansion of
$(1-1)^n$
by the binomial theorem.

The second one:

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{l=0}^n \sum_{k=l}^n (-1)^{k-l} \binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{l}s_l 
&=\sum_{l=0}^n s_l\sum_{k=l}^n (-1)^{k-l} \dfrac{n!k!}{k!(n-k)!l!(k-l)!}\\ 
&=\sum_{l=0}^n s_l\dfrac{n!}{l!}\sum_{k=l}^n (-1)^{k-l} \dfrac{1}{(n-k)!(k-l)!}\\ 
&=\sum_{l=0}^n s_l\dfrac{n!}{l!(n-l)!}\sum_{k=l}^n (-1)^{k-l} \dfrac{(n-l)!}{(n-k)!(k-l)!}\\ 
&=\sum_{l=0}^n s_l\binom{n}{l}\sum_{k=l}^n (-1)^{k-l} \binom{n-l}{k-l}\\ 
&=\sum_{l=0}^n s_l\binom{n}{l}\sum_{k=0}^{n-l} (-1)^{k} \binom{n-l}{k}\\ 
&= s_n\\
\end{array}
$

The first one:

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{l=0}^k \binom{n}{k} \binom{k}{l} (-1)^{k-l} s_l 
&=\sum_{l=0}^n \sum_{k=l}^n \binom{n}{k} \binom{k}{l} (-1)^{k-l} s_l 
\end{array}\\
$

and this is the second one.