# Show that $\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{l=0}^k t(k, l) =\sum_{l=0}^n \sum_{k=l}^n t(k, l) $.

Tags: summation, induction

This is inspired
by my answer to
[$\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{l=0}^k \binom{n}{k} \binom{k}{l} (-1)^{k-l} s_l ?= \sum_{l=0}^n \sum_{k=l}^n (-1)^{n-k} \binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{l}s_l $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305143/sum-k-0n-sum-l-0k-binomnk-binomkl-1k-l-s-l-sum-l-0).

Show that
$\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{l=0}^k t(k, l)
=\sum_{l=0}^n \sum_{k=l}^n t(k, l)
$.

Here is my proof
using induction.

Let
$A(n)
=\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{l=0}^k t(k, l)
$
and
$B(n)
=\sum_{l=0}^n \sum_{k=l}^n t(k, l)
$.

Claim:

$A(n) = B(n)
$.

Proof.

$A(0) = t(0, 0)$
and
$B(0) = t(0, 0)
=A(0)$.

$\begin{array}\\
A(n+1)
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \sum_{l=0}^k t(k, l)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{l=0}^k t(k, l)+\sum_{l=0}^{n+1} t(n+1, l)\\
&=A(n)+\sum_{l=0}^{n+1} t(n+1, l)\\
\end{array}
$

$\begin{array}\\
B(n+1)
&=\sum_{l=0}^{n+1} \sum_{k=l}^{n+1} t(k, l)\\
&=\sum_{l=0}^{n+1} (\sum_{k=l}^{n} t(k, l)+t(n+1, l))\\
&=\sum_{l=0}^{n+1} \sum_{k=l}^{n} t(k, l)+\sum_{l=0}^{n+1} t(n+1, l)\\
&=\sum_{l=0}^{n} \sum_{k=l}^{n} t(k, l)+\sum_{k=n+1}^{n} t(k, l)+\sum_{l=0}^{n+1} t(n+1, l)\\
&=B(n)+\sum_{l=0}^{n+1} t(n+1, l)\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$A(n+1)-A(n)
=B(n+1)-B(n)$.

Since $A(0) = B(0)$,
then
$A(n) = B(n)$
for all $n$.

Comment: Seems correct. If $t(k,l)$ is symmetric in its arguments, we also have $\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{l=0}^k t(k, l)=\frac 1 2\left(\left(\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{l=0}^n t(k, l)  \right) + \sum_{i=1}^n t(i,i)\right)$

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternate proof for this:

Since we know nothing about $t$, we don't really need it at all.

We therefore define
$$\phi: P(\mathbb N^2) \to \mathbb R,\qquad M\mapsto \sum_{i\in M} t(i)
$$

Using it we can just look at the 2-tuples being created by the sums:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{l=0}^k t(k, l) =\sum_{l=0}^n \sum_{k=l}^n t(k, l) \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad \phi(M_1) = \phi(M_2)
$$

Where

\begin{align}
M_1 
\\&= \bigcup_{k=0}^n \bigcup_{l=0}^k \{(k,l)\} 
\\&= \{(k,l)\in\mathbb N^2\mid 0\le k \le n \land 0\le l \le k \}
\\&= \{(k,l)\in\mathbb N^2\mid 0\le l\le k \le n\} 
\end{align}

And similarly

\begin{align}
M_2 
\\&= \bigcup_{l=0}^n \bigcup_{k=l}^n \{(k, l)\}
\\&= \{(k,l)\in\mathbb N^2\mid 0\le l \le n \land l\le k \le n \}
\\&= \{(k,l)\in\mathbb N^2\mid 0\le l\le k \le n\} 
\end{align}

And therefore we have $M_1=M_2$