# How did Rudin change the order of the double sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n\sum_{m=0}^n\binom nma^{n-m}(x-a)^m$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits, summation

I see many people change the order of sum but I don't understand how they did that.

Is there is a way to change the order of the sum,  $\sum\limits_{k=a}^n\sum\limits_{j=b}^m X_{j,k}$ and $\sum\limits_{k=a}^n\sum\limits_{j=b}^k X_{j,k}$?

An example of this is Theorem 8.4 from *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*.

---

Theorem 8.4: Suppose
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$$
the series converging in $|x|<R$. If $-R<a<R$, then f can be expanded in a power series about the point $x=a$ which converges in $|x-a|<R-|a|$, and
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n\ \ \ (|x-a|<R-|a|)$$

Proof we have
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n[(x-a)+a]^n$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n\sum_{m=0}^n\binom nma^{n-m}(x-a)^m$$
$$\color{red}{=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\Big{[}\sum_{n=m}^\infty\binom nmc_na^{n-m}\Big{]}(x-a)^m}$$

Comment: Your last example is a bit different than your original question.  If it's the last example you really wanted to ask about, look up the **Cauchy product**.  It involves re-indexing rather than just swapping finite sums and limits.

Comment: what about my first example @BrianMoehring

Comment: @BrianMoehring can you please explain to me how rudin changed the order of sum ?

Comment: I changed PMA to what it abbreviates.  It's not a good idea to expect that everyone knows what "PMA" means when it takes very little time to write out the real title of the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to prove that
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{m=0}^k f(k,m)=\sum_{m=0}^n \sum_{k=m}^n f(k,m) $$
to show that firstly we assume $f(k,m)=0 \text{ for } m>k$ and using the fact
$$ \sum_{k=0}^a f(k)=\sum_{k=0}^b f(k)-\sum_{k=a+1}^{b} f(k) $$
So
$$ \sum_{m=0}^k f(k,m)=\sum_{m=0}^n f(k,m)-\sum_{m=k+1}^n f(k,m)=\sum_{m=0}^n f(k,m)$$
then
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{m=0}^k f(k,m)=\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{m=0}^n f(k,m)=\sum_{m=0}^n \sum_{k=0}^n f(k,m) $$
now we have
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n f(k,m)=\sum_{k=m}^n f(k,m)-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} f(k,m)=\sum_{k=m}^n f(k,m) $$
finally we get (with vanished the function $f(n,m) \text{ for } m>n$ )
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{m=0}^k f(k,m)=\sum_{m=0}^n \sum_{k=m}^n f(k,m) $$

Answer (score 2):

You should think about this as analogous to changing the order of integration in a double integral. Sketch the region $0\le y<\infty$, $0\le x\le y$. It is an infinite triangle, if you like, between the line $x=y$ and the $y$-axis. You can equally well write it as $0\le x<\infty$, $x\le y<\infty$.

The same thing works with the region defined with integer coordinates. $\{0\le n<\infty, 0\le m\le n\}$ is precisely the same set as $\{0\le m<\infty, m\le n<\infty\}$.

Comment: hmmm... I want to see how this can be proved rigorously

Comment: There's nothing unrigorous about what I said. I thought your issue was the actual limits of summation that appear. In the case of integrals, you want to appeal to Fubini's Theorem to change the order of integration; in the case of series, Rudin applies Theorem 8.3, immediately preceding, and he justifies it in full rigor in the proof of Theorem 8.4. If you want to make the business with the region *look* more rigorous, put in the characteristic function $\chi_R$ of the region: $\chi_R(i,j) = \begin{cases} 1, & (i,j)\in R \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$, and apply Theorem 8.3 verbatim.

Comment: ahaaa now I understand 

Thank you very much sir

Comment: You're most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the intuition as to how to find the alternative representation of the first two sums, then you're looking for a double counting argument: Make a table where the cell in the i-th row and j-th column is $X_{i,j}$. Now you get the first representation by summing up the table elements row after row, and the second representation by summing up the table elements column after column.

If you're looking for proofs, then there are many ways. One can e.g. try to turn the above into a rigorous proof or reduce the problem to set notation.

For your second example, take a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305199/show-that-sum-k-0n-sum-l-0k-tk-l-sum-l-0n-sum-k-ln-tk-l/3305611#3305611), which is a slightly simpler variant.

If you in the same vein try to reduce your first example to set notation, you will find that both $\sum\limits_{k=a}^n\sum\limits_{j=b}^m X_{j,k}$ and $\sum_{j=b}^m \sum_{k=a}^n X_{k,j}$ reduce to the sum over the elements of the set $\{(j,k)\in\mathbb N^2\mid b\le j\le m \land k\le a \le n\}$.

Comment: Sadly, I think the point of the question was in the title, and not in the body of the question. For finite (double) sums there isn't much issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just think that

\begin{align*}\sum_{k=a}^n \sum_{j=b}^m X_{k,j}&=[X_{a,b}+X_{a,b+1}+...+X_{a,m}]+...+[X_{n,b}+X_{n,b+1}+...+X_{n,m}]\\&=\sum_{j=b}^m \sum_{k=a}^n X_{k,j}\end{align*}

Comment: This isn’t exactly what OP is asking, since this is just reordering a double sum, while OP seems to be asking what a cauchy product is.

Comment: I answered to the first question. Afterwards the title of the question changed.